# Video play in unity3d skybox

Tags: unity, c#, video, skybox, 360-video

**I want to play 360 video in skybox**. Is there any direct way avaiable to do this task. One long, boring, inefficient  procedure which seems that

1. Convert 360 to frames
2. Convert frames into cubmap
3. Use that cubeMap in skybox and Programatically change it's textures(Frame) quickly so that video effects shown

This is the long task which seems to me possible but is there any other way available?

Comment: using unity? no i don't believe so. I don't think unity supports the direct use of video, you would have to cut frames and make it a box.

Comment: You can probably play it into MovieTexture, grab the result from the screen, apply some math to convert it into cubemap, then render in on the skybox. Writing custom shader and skybox can be a good idea.

Comment: @MaximKamalov you should be able to do this more simply - write a shader that reads the MovieTexture directly, performing the appropriate math to sample the needed texels from it for each pixel on the screen. No need for screengrabbing or constructing a whole cubemap for unseen parts of the "sky."

Comment: In fact, [see this answer for an example of such a shader](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/148178/39518)