# Project 360 video on the inside of a iso sphere / polygon sphere

Tags: unity, 3d, textures, projection, 360-video

I'm creating a game in Unity. I have a iso sphere or polygon sphere, and I want to project a 360 video on the inside of the polygon sphere.

I've learned thow to put a 360 video on the inside of a sphere, following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36423846/flip-normals-in-unity-3d-spheres), but how can I do it inside a polygon sphere, since the 360 video was created based on a sphere but not a polygon sphere?

```
Shader "Flip Normals" {
    Properties {
        _MainTex ("Base (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader {

        Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" }

        Cull Off

        CGPROGRAM

        #pragma surface surf Lambert vertex:vert
        sampler2D _MainTex;

        struct Input {
            float2 uv_MainTex;
            float4 color : COLOR;
        };

        void vert(inout appdata_full v) {
            v.normal.xyz = v.normal * -1;
        }

        void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
             fixed3 result = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex);
             o.Albedo = result.rgb;
             o.Alpha = 1;
        }

        ENDCG

    }

      Fallback "Diffuse"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The principle isn't really any different.

Inside the fragment shader you compute a latitude & longitude by converting the shaded point's offset from the center of the sphere from Cartesian to spherical coordinates.

Then you use that lat/long pair as the texture coordinate to look up into your video texture (assuming your video is in equirectangular projection - you'd use different formulas for other projections)

Even with a mesh that's already unwrapped in lat-long format, you should really do this mapping in the shader anyway - affine texture mapping alone can't handle the distortion at the poles of the sphere correctly.

[You can see an example of this texture mapping distortion and how to fix it with a shader in one of my earlier answers on the subject](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/148178/39518).

Comment: can you please provide a more detailed instruction? Or links to related links or tutorials where I can learn? I'm quite new to Unity and don't have much experience with shader to achieve this.

Comment: Yep - linked to one of my earlier answers. Don't forget to search; chances are you're not the first one to have a particular problem. ;) I've added a [tag:360-video] tag to the 11 questions we have on the subject so far to make them easier to find.