# Unity 3D Image Distortion

Tags: unity, 3d, virtual-reality

I'm trying to make a 3D tour for cardboard. I'm putting my 3d image inside a sphere with a shader but I've noticed this problem. And the middle of the image is looking kinda wavey and distorted.

[image]

Comment: Did you make the 3D image yourself? Do other 3D images work as or have the same issue? By "3D Images" do you mean a [Skydome Image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skybox_(video_games))?

Comment: Yes I did. I've added a picture of the problem.

Comment: If you made the image yourself, have you confirmed if the problem is on the code you are using to display it or in the image itself?

Comment: Well, I don't think it's code related. Can it be the scale  or shader ?

Comment: I can't say be cause I don't know how your project is set up. That's why I'm asking all these questions. The more information you share here, the more likely someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Inside a sphere I've got my 3D image and the middle of the image looks like I'm looking like behind a glass of water.

Comment: Can you tell us how you're "putting my 3D image inside a sphere"? Walk us through the steps. Show us your source image. Show us what material/shader you're using on your sphere. Show us how the sphere mesh and UV unwrap is set up, if you're using UV mapping.

Comment: If your source image uses equirectangular mapping (latitude-longitude), then [this previous Q&A might help you correct your mapping onto the sphere](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/148167/39518).